# How do I put labels on this tree?

Tags: tikz-qtree, qtree

[image]

I want to put labels on this tree as shown in square brackets. I have a working code which generates this tree.

```
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}    
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={minimum width=2em,draw,circle},
     blank/.style={draw=none},
     edge from parent/.style=
     {draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
     level distance=1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\label{binary tree}
\Tree
[.$\vee$ 
$A$ 
[.$\wedge$ 
    $B$
    [.$\vee$ $C$ $D$
    ]
]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always give your nodes some names

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}    
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={minimum width=2em,draw,circle},
     blank/.style={draw=none},
     edge from parent/.style=
     {draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
     level distance=1.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\label{binary tree}
\Tree
[.\node (1) {$\vee$}; 
\node (A) {$A$}; 
[.\node (2) {$\wedge$}; 
    \node (B) {$B$};
    [.\node (3) {$\vee$}; \node (C) {$C$}; \node (D) {$D$};
    ]
]
]
\path (1.east) node[right] {[a]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]